# Fastest/One-liner way to print XML node's XPath in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

What's the fastest/one-liner way to print the current nodes xpath, or just "path/to/node", in Ruby with Nokogiri?

So this:

```
<nodeA>
    <nodeB>
        <nodeC/>
    </nodeB>
</nodeA>
```

to this (say we've gone down to nodeC by processing xml.children.each, etc...):

```
"nodeA/nodeB/nodeC"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
node.path
```

You can find the full documentation of node here: http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html

Comment: Is there a method to do this in reverse?

Comment: You mean like `node = document.at_css(path)` !?